# Is it possible to extend function from library in such case?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-c++, .net-4.0

I have a .Net library. say with 2 public functions. say one is `Summmator` which takes 2 arguments and does `A+B`. Another function `simpleMultiplicator` which takes 2 arguments: a number to multiplicate and count of times it should be multiplicated. A `simpleMultiplicator` function when called uses `Summmator` function. So it is my library. It is compiled into dll for .net4. In my programm I want to extend or modify Summator function so that when I call simpleMultiplicator it would use my modification of original Summator function. Is it possible in .net4, how to do it?

(C#, visual-C++)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on how you design your classes. You state that your library exports two public functions, but they need to be defined on a class either as static or instance method, so you can make use of object-orientated principles like inheritance or polymorphism to achieve what you want.

Here is an example using inheritance:

```
namespace MyLibrary
{
    public class MyMath
    {
        // Be aware of the virtual keyword which enables overriding the method
        public virtual int Summmator(int a, int b)
        {
            return a + b;
        }

        public int SimpleMultiplicator(int a, int b)
        {
            int result = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < b; i++)
            {
                result = Summmator(result, a);
            }
        }
    }
}

namespace MyProgram
{
    using MyLibrary;

    public class MyExtendedMath : MyMath
    {
        public override int Summmator(int a, int b)
        {
            return a + 2 * b;
        }
    }

    public static class Program
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            MyMath math = new MyExtendedMath();
            int result = math.SimpleMultiplicator(2, 3);

            Console.WriteLine(result);
        }
    }
}
```

Another way is to use polymorphism:

```
namespace MyLibrary
{
    public interface ISummmator
    {
        int Summmator(int a, int b);
    }

    public class Summmator : ISummator
    {
        public int Summmator(int a, int b)
        {
            return a + b;
        }
    }

    public static class MyMath
    {
        public static int SimpleMultiplicator(int a, int b, ISummmator summmator)
        {
            int result = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < b; i++)
            {
                result = summmator.Summmator(result, a);
            }
        }
    }
}

namespace MyProgram
{
    using MyLibrary;

    public class MySummmator : ISummmator
    {
        public int Summmator(int a, int b)
        {
            return a + 2 * b;
        }
    }

    public static class Program
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            int result = MyMath.SimpleMultiplicator(2, 3, new MySummmator());

            Console.WriteLine(result);
        }
    }
}
```

Best Regards,
Oliver Hanappi

Answer (score 1):

First, I'd objectify these things. So you have a Summator which provides a sum function, and a SimpleMultiplicator which provides a multiply function. Then, you add the Summator to the SimpleMultiplicator in the default case. For example,

```
class SimpleMultiplicator
{
    public SimpleMultiplicator()
    {
      this.summator = new Summator();
    }

    public int Mult(int a, int b)
    {
      // ...
      this.summator.sum(something, somethingelse);
      // etc
    }
```

Then you create another constructor where you can override the default Summator:

```
  public SimpleMultiplicator(Summator summator)
  {
    this.summator = summator;
  }
```

So if you want to change the summation function, you create a new Summator-based class, override its sum() method and pass it on to the SimpleMultiplicator constructur.